# Filter the values in a variable in a dataframe which match a regular expression using grep in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have data which looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID_num = c("BGR9876", "BNG3421", "GTH4567", "YOP9824", "Child 1", "2JAZZ", "TYH7654"),
  date_created = "19/07/1983"
)
```

I would like to filter the dataframe so that I only keep the rows where ID_num follows the pattern ABC1234. I am new to using regular expressions in grep, and I am getting this wrong. This is what I am trying

```
data_clean <- data %>%
  filter(grep("[A-Z]{3}[1:9]{4}", ID_num))
```

Which gives me the error `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector`

This is my desired output

```
data_clean <- data.frame(
  ID_num = c("BGR9876", "BNG3421", "GTH4567", "YOP9824", "TYH7654"),
  date_created = "19/07/1983"
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `1:9` should be `1-9` and it would be `grepl` along with `^` to specify the start of the string and `$` for the end of the string

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   filter(grepl("^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$", ID_num))
#   ID_num date_created
#1 BGR9876   19/07/1983
#2 BNG3421   19/07/1983
#3 GTH4567   19/07/1983
#4 YOP9824   19/07/1983
#5 TYH7654   19/07/1983
```

`filter` expects a logical vector, `grep` returns numeric index while `grepl` return logical vector

---

Or if we want to use `grep`, use `slice` which expects numeric index

```
data %>%
   slice(grep("^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$", ID_num))
```

---

A similar option in `tidyverse` would be to use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
data %>%
    filter(str_detect(ID_num, "^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$"))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
subset(data, grepl("^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$", ID_num))
```

Or with `Extract`

```
data[grepl("^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$", data$ID_num),]
```

---

Note that this will specifically find the pattern of 3 upper case letters followed by 4 digits, and not match

```
grepl("[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}", "ABGR9876923")
#[1] TRUE

grepl("^[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{4}$", "ABGR9876923")
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grepl` with the pattern

```
data[grepl("[A-Z]{3}\\d{4}", data$ID_num), ]

#   ID_num date_created
#1 BGR9876   19/07/1983
#2 BNG3421   19/07/1983
#3 GTH4567   19/07/1983
#4 YOP9824   19/07/1983
#7 TYH7654   19/07/1983
```

Or in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(grepl("[A-Z]{3}\\d{4}", ID_num))
```